# setup.icloud.com two-step verification

Tags: python, ios, backup, icloud

I'm playing around with [iLoot](https://github.com/hackappcom/iloot), an open source app that let's you download iCloud backups and I was wondering how it is possible to implement the two factor authentication to it.

I have 2fa enabled on my account and what I get on the first request is this:

First request:

```
        auth = "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode("%s:%s" % (login, password))
authenticateResponse = plist_request("setup.icloud.com", "POST", "/setup/authenticate/$APPLE_ID$", "", {"Authorization": auth})
```

plist_request is just a normal python ([request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)) function that request from the url and returns the parsed xml.

First response (in xml format):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>protocolVersion</key>
    <string>2</string>

    <key>title</key>
    <string>Verification Required</string>

    <key>localizedError</key>
    <string>MOBILEME_TERMS_OF_SERVICE_UPDATE</string>

    <key>message</key>
    <string>This Apple ID is protected with two-step verification. To sign in, you must verify your identity.</string>

</dict>
</plist>
Request /setup/authenticate/$APPLE_ID$ returned code 409
```

In case anyone knows what the next call would be to input the two-step verification code, it could help to figure it out.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @BenyBoariu This was a weekend project of mine so I stopped looking for solutions after that, will post here if I ever got back to it. Please let me know if you found anything later :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm an iOS guy, not backend guy, but my backend team solved this on their side by using the app-specific password, instead of tokens.

This is how user can generate an app-specific password: [Generate App-Specific Password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397)

Then simply use the email and this password, instead of the token formed by dsPrsID:mmeAuthToken. As I learnt for my teammates, you don't have to do base64 encode, just use that new password, and the url:'https://caldav.icloud.com/'

Hope this helps. It was a nightmare for us, no help at all on the internet.

**UPDATE**

For more info, these are the steps I used on my side (iOS):

1. I call *https://setup.icloud.com/setup/authenticate/"email@email.com"*, by setting "Basic email:password" as base64 string to "Authorization" http header field.
2. I check response status code. If 401, it means the password you are sending is an app specific password, so then I send this password (and email) directly to my server, via our internal API, and they are using it to call iCloud APIs, and return me calendars, etc.
3. If response status code is 409, it means that user tried to login with a normal password, but his account is enabled for 2fa, and I display an error, warning user to go and retrieve his app-specific-password, and use that one, which will lead to step 2, above.

I am not saying this is the only way, but this worked for me. Also, I don't exactly know what's going on on server side, but they are using directly that app-specific-passwrod (and probably the email), to do the job.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know Apple also offers App-Specific passwords. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Welcome, I hope it helps others, because for us it was so bad, digging everywhere to find the solution, and almost nothing. Apple should definitely improve their docs.

Comment: @BenyBoariu could you give more details? I tried only to change the dsPrsID:mmeAuthToken to appleId:password tuple and it doesnt work..

Comment: @idog I updated the answer, please let me know if it's clearer now. I still do miss the server side, I am not sure what's going on exactly there, but as I've been told, they use the app-specific-password to retrieve whatever needed from iCloud.

Comment: @BenyBoariu thanks for your quick reply, do you by any chance have a way to know what going on the server side? This is the part that I'm missing.

Comment: @idog I will try to find out, but probably only tomorrow.

Comment: @BenyBoariu any info?

Comment: @realshadow Sorry, but long time passed, I no longer have access to that code.

Answer (score 2):

you have to replace $appliid$ with your appleid...
then you get mmeAuthToken, dsPrsID

https setup.icloud.com/setup/get_account_settings
dsPrsID:mmeAuthToken as basic auth
returns:
mmeAuthToken
(new/other one!!)

the next request for the backup information didn't work for me...
i am not that far right now...

docs i've worked with before:

https://www.elcomsoft.com/PR/recon_2013.pdf
https://deepsec.net/docs/Slides/2013/DeepSec_2013_Vladimir_Katalov_-_Cracking_And_Analyzing_Apple_iCloud_Protocols.pdf

Thanks for your post! Brought me to iLoot.

Comment: sorry, didn't read that far about 2fa. don't think what described in the papers is 2fa